# How to re-validate the coupons in magento2 before place an order

Tags: magento2, checkout, coupon, coupon-codes, place-order

at the time of place order re-validate the coupon-code used in the checkout. If code has already been used, the customer should not be able to place an order. Error message should say "Valid discount code required to complete order."

please provide any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: You can use events which triggers before place order like `sales_order_place_before`, `checkout_submit_before`, etc.

Comment: is it validate the coupon code?

Comment: Not sure, but at least you can start from it.